# create-react-app doesn't create src and public folder even though its the latest version

Tags: node.js, npm, create-react-app

I have been trying to create react project with create-react-app. But whenever I do so, I get this:
[image]
As you can see, I have tried all the solutions given in previous solutions, but it does not work. Nothing happens after done.

1. I have reinstalled node twice but no avail
2. I have tried creating app with yarn, no avail
3. I have also globally removed npm and added again. No avail.
   Please help.
   My current software versions:
4. windows 10
5. node version 14.16.0
6. npm version 6.14.11

Answer (score 0):

Try following steps :

```
npm rm -g create-react-app

npm install -g create-react-app

npx create-react-app my-app
```

If you still facing same issue then please visit following links:

[public, src,and scripts folder not created while installing react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8088)

[create-react-app doesn't generate public and src folders thus cannot get started](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8374)

Comment: Well that's the issue I am facing. Inside the app folder, there are only 3 sub folders/files: node_modules, package.json and yarn.lock. Nothing else gets created.

Comment: I don't find any issues. Tried with `node` & `npm` latest version. Last but not the least, avoid `globally` always and will you please try again in a different located folder?

Comment: I had tried it again and I just did the same once again. The issue still persists.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please have a look.

Comment: I did that too. No avail.

Comment: Please visit this https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8088 link